# Doctrine Hydrate joined Entities into one array-entry

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, entity, left-join, resultset

I'm currently encountering some problems with Doctrine Hydration. I'm using ZF2 to build an API and therefore i need to build some queries that make use of joins.

For now they look somewhat like this:

```
$qb->select(array('r, a'))
   ->from('Release\Entity\Release', 'r')
   ->leftJoin(
       'Artist\Entity\Artist', a',
       \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'a.id = r.artist'
     )
   ->orderBy('r.id', 'ASC');
```

So if i hydrate the Result with `AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY` the result will be an extra array entry for each joined table/entity.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [artist] => 1
            [title] => A super nice Release
            [digital_release] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2014-01-25 00:00:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
                )

            [physical_release] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2014-01-25 00:00:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [first_name] => John
            [last_name] => Doe
            [artist_name] => JD and the Beat-Machines
            [created_at] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2015-04-17 13:16:18.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
                )

            [updated_at] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2015-04-17 13:16:18.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [artist] => 14
            [title] => Some other nice album
            [digital_release] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2014-02-01 00:00:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
                )

            [physical_release] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2014-02-01 00:00:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
                )

        )

    [...]
)
```

As you can see the artist of the corresponding release [0] is stored into array-key [1].

If I finally print the result as new `JsonModel($result)` this doesn't seem a workable way to me.

What i want to achieve is some result like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [artist] => Array
                     (
                         [id] => 1
                         [first_name] => John
                         [last_name] => Doe
                         [artist_name] => JD and the Beat-Machines
                         [created_at] => DateTime Object
                             (
                                 [date] => 2015-04-17 13:16:18.000000
                                 [timezone_type] => 3
                                 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
                              )

                         [updated_at] => DateTime Object
                              (
                                  [date] => 2015-04-17 13:16:18.000000
                                  [timezone_type] => 3
                                  [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
                              )

                      )
            [title] => A super nice Release
            [digital_release] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2014-01-25 00:00:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
                )

            [physical_release] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2014-01-25 00:00:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [artist] => Array
                     (
                         [id] => 14

                         [...]

                      )
            [title] => Some other nice album
            [digital_release] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2014-02-01 00:00:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
                )

            [physical_release] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2014-02-01 00:00:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
                )

        )

    [...]
)
```

Maybe someone has a helpful advice how to get such an output :)

I've already tried to use `AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_SCALAR`, which comes a bit closer to what i want, but the result of the joined table is not a sub-array of the joined column.

Thanks in advance for every helpful hint :)

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your mapping it's not good i think you have not a relation between Release and Artist.

You have to set a relation OneToMany between Artist and Release. Like this :

```
On artist side
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Release\Entity\Release", mappedBy="artist")
 */
protected $release;

And Release side
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Artist\Entity\Artist", inversedBy="release")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="artist", referencedColumnName="idArtist", onDelete="RESTRICT")
 */
protected $artist;
```

Don't forget to the Artist side to instanciate a collection like this :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->release= new ArrayCollection();
}
```

with this use :

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
```

With this you can set your release entity and set the artist whith an artist object. You'll have the result you want.

```
$release = new Release;
$artist = new Artist;
$release->setArtist($artist);
```

**EDIT**
When you have your data, you have to populate your entity with it.

If you have a Form, you have to use DoctrineHydrator to achieve this, your object will be correctly hydrated, from your form. This may need to dig into doctrine documentation ;)
If your data comes from anywhere else, you can populate your entity with your entity's setters.

For e.g :

```
$relaseEntity->setDate($data['date']); // Be carefull to Datetime object for this
$releaseEntity->setName($data['name']);
```

And goes on...

Comment: Hey Hooli, thanks for the helpful comment on this! 
So your mapping example works well, but in the action - when i make a new instance of release - i don't really know how to fill the Entity-Object with my data. I mean: new Release means one single item, but my query builds a list of all items in the query. so i got my $query which holds the result of my whole query (which is done with the QueryBuilder) and on the other hand i've got this nice but empty entity-object...
Maybe a dumb question but: How do you bring these two things together?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply: I tried it and it works for the object itself. But i cannot pass the object as jsonModel, since the properties of the entity are protected and the json therefor will be empty.
If this last step will work, then everything would be fine.

Comment: Okay, i finally got it! Simply typecasted the object into an array. This needed some workaround, but finally it works! Thanks a lot :)